# No signalr/hubs in SignalR Core Alpha 2

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm new to SignalR and trying to implement it in a clean new ASP.NET Core 2.0 app following instructions here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/

After adding the NuGet package and installing the client side scripts, I run my app and go to `localhost:1234/signalr/hubs`, I get nothing.

Does alpha 2 not generate the on-the-fly script?

Comment: hub proxies are not needed because there is just one hub per connection in the new SignalR

Answer (score 0):

SignalR Hub Transport Protocols [spec](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/specs/TransportProtocols.md) says that it is supporting: WebSockets, Server-Sent Events, Long Polling and HTTP Post.
Browsing directly to the hub endpoint (HTTP GET) is probably giving you `400 - Bad Request`. To establish connection you have to:

1. Make an HTTP OPTION requires to the endpoint (localhost:1234/signalr/hubs). You will receive response like this:

   {
       "connectionId": "**10ff7588-01be-4768-9e0a-49326a07a988**",
       "availableTransports": [
           "WebSockets",
           "ServerSentEvents",
           "LongPolling"
       ]
   }
2. Take connectionid from response and issue HTTP Post to:
   localhost:1234/signalr/hubs?id=**10ff7588-01be-4768-9e0a-49326a07a988**
   You should be able to see empty HTTP response.

Alpha2 [release notes](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/releases) doesn't state anything about on-the-fly script generation. I recoomend you to check out the [samples](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples).